# How to combine these specific Javascript statements?

Tags: javascript, html

1.I include what the two lines i want to combine in the first comment of the code. If you can point me to what i need to do it would really help. I just started javascript a couple days ago. If u can recommend any books please tell me. im currently reading the murach series of books and its really helping.

```
    /*The two statements i want to combine are 
    entry = parseInt(entry);
    var score1 = entry; */

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">  
        <title>Average Test Scores</title>
        <script>
            var entry;
            var average;
            var total = 0;

            //get 3 scores from user and add them together
            entry = prompt("Enter test score");
            entry = parseInt(entry);
            var score1 = entry;
            total = total + score1;

            entry = prompt("Enter test score");
            entry = parseInt(entry);
            var score2;
            total = total + score2;

            entry = prompt("Enter test score");
            entry = parseInt(entry);
            var score3 = entry;
            total = total + score3;

            //calculate the average
            average = parseInt(total/3);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            document.write("<h1>The Test Scores App</h1>");
            document.write("Score 1 = " + score1 + "<br>" +
                "Score 2 = " + score2 + "<br>" +
                "Score 3 = " + score3 + "<br><br>" +
                "Average score = " + average + "<br><br>");
        </script>
        Thanks for using the Test Scores application!
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `var score1 = parseInt(entry); */`

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. What do you mean by combine those lines? `var score1 = parseInt(entry);`?  Why all the extra code and not just those two lines? I'm getting the sense you have more specific questions that you aren't directly asking.

Comment: This is an exercise in the book. It told me to combine these two lines somehow. so i just posted the entire document so everyone can see.

Comment: @Rayon thanks you answered by question. I dont know how to close this topic or say my question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

[**`Addition assignment`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment), *The `addition assignment` operator adds the value of the `right operand` to a variable and assigns the result to the variable.*

[**`Unary plus (+)`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), *The `unary plus operator` precedes its operand and evaluates to its operand but attempts to converts it into a `number`, if it isn't already.*

Simplified version:

```js
var total = 0;
var score1 = +prompt("Enter test score"); //Cast it to Number
total += score1; //Add it to total
var score2 = +prompt("Enter test score");
total += score2;
var score3 = +prompt("Enter test score");
total += score3;
var average = parseInt(total / 3);
document.write("<h1>The Test Scores App</h1>");
document.write("Score 1 = " + score1 + "<br>" +
  "Score 2 = " + score2 + "<br>" +
  "Score 3 = " + score3 + "<br><br>" +
  "Average score = " + average + "<br><br>");
```